# ERROR: Dependency "wingpanel" not found

Tags: wingpanel, indicator-sound

I'm trying to build the sound indicator, but I'm running into dependencies issues.

I'm on elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera.
I've cloned the [wingpanel-indicator-sound](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-sound) repo.
When building I'm getting this error:

> meson.build:28:0: ERROR:  Dependency "wingpanel" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake

Looks like I've got the relevant libs installed:

```
apt search libwingpanel 
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libwingpanel-2.0-0/bionic,now 2.3.2+r454+pkg48~ubuntu5.1.5.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  A super sexy space-saving top panel

libwingpanel-2.0-dev/bionic,now 2.3.2+r454+pkg48~ubuntu5.1.5.1 amd64 [installed]
  Library to build plugins for WingPanel (development files)
```

I've got the following version of the wingpanel:

```
apt show wingpanel                
Package: wingpanel
Version: 2.3.2+r454+pkg48~ubuntu5.1.5.1
```

There is a change the indicator is already counting on the next version of elementary OS, but I'm not seeing that many updates.

- https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-sound/compare/2.1.8...master
- https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-sound/releases

I've build this indicator in the past.
https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-sound/pulls?q=author%3Apeteruithoven+is%3Apr

I was hoping to do some reseach for this issue:
https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-sound/issues/185

Answer (score 0):

This is a recent change for how [libwingpanel](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel) is packaged.
See the commit [here](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/commit/5cda994e40ee4101ae2f370ec40d7fe5d48bca46).
Checkout the related change in wingpanel-indicator-sound in [this commit](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-sound/commit/845e631c420cca84a4807ec08f201be439a9ae88).
Perhaps you need to build and install the latest wingpanel from source before building wingpanel-indicator-sound.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Tried building Wingpanel (I have in the past), but that seems to depend on libmutter 6 or 7, while I seem to have 2. This all makes me think I can't build the latest version in elementary OS Hera.

Comment: I checked out the last tagged version (2.1.8) and that seems to build. It from before the commit you mention, so that's probably why. 
https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-sound/releases/tag/2.1.8

Comment: If the libmutter dependency bumped, I would think its safest and easiest to use elementary OS 6 to build the latest version, but I'm glad you've got a version building.